# libQGLViewer how to draw withouth clearing buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, draw, framebuffer, qglviewer

I'm using [libQGLViewer](http://libqglviewer.com/) in my project to draw the trajectory of a robot. To this end, I started from the code of the [simpleViewer](http://libqglviewer.com/examples/simpleViewer.html) provided in the examples.

To do my stuff, I put these lines of code in the `draw` function:

```
void Viewer::draw()
{

  glPushMatrix();
  for (auto pose : poses)
  {
    std::vector<float> m;
    poseToVector(pose, m);

    glPushMatrix();
    multMatrix(m);
    drawReferenceSystem();
    glPopMatrix();
  }
  glPopMatrix();
}
```

where the `poseToVector`, `multMatrix` and `drawReferenceSystem` functions are OpenGL wrappers to implement the desired functionalities.

Now, my problem is that the `poses` vector is filled at each iteration of my code with a new pose. Thus, what I'm doing now is that at iteration 1 I'm drawing pose 1, at iteration 2 I'm drawing pose 1 and 2, at iteration 3 I'm drawing pose 1,2 and 3, and so on.

For this reason, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to perform this operation. However, if I just get the `back` of the vector I will see at each time instant only the last pose. I guess that this is because every time the `draw` function is called the frame buffer is cleared.

Therefore, my question is: is it possible to avoid clearing the buffer or I'm just saying bullshit?

Comment: Are you calling glClear somewhere? Don't call glClear and then the old drawing won't be erased.

Comment: I don't. I guess it's called somewhere in the qgl library. Do you know if there's a way to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`preDraw`](http://libqglviewer.com/refManual/classQGLViewer.html#a9c6b3ec107b4f010cf1fcd8c51ca92e4) clears the screen and resets matrices.
You could subclass QGLViewer and override it to drop the clearing behavior.

The [default implementation](https://github.com/GillesDebunne/libQGLViewer/blob/master/QGLViewer/qglviewer.cpp#L323-L332) is:

```
void QGLViewer::preDraw() {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // this line should be removed here or in a sublass.

  // GL_PROJECTION matrix
  camera()->loadProjectionMatrix();
  // GL_MODELVIEW matrix
  camera()->loadModelViewMatrix();

  Q_EMIT drawNeeded();
}
```